# Auto Incrémentation on a non primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am looking to make a unique field on one of my columns, and I would love that the field would be filled automatically. I have an ID column that works great, but I want an other column called "reference" that behave like an ID. So I tried this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="integer", length=255, unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $reference;
```

Of course, I have this error when I try to post something in the db:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'reference' cannot be null

I tried to put logic in the controller, but when I try to send 2 requests at the same time, the generated reference is the same for both..

So how could I make this `reference` field automatic?